# How to print even key value pair in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have scenario where i want to print only even data [ index and value ]

**My code :**

```
import pandas as pd
data=[1,2,3,4]
s=pd.Series(data)

var=['a','b','c','d']
sd=pd.Series(data,var)

for i in sd:
    m=i
    print(m)
    if i%2==0:
        print(i,var[i]=m) 
        
        
    else:
        pass
```

**Following is my error :**

```
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

    print(i,var[i]=m)
```

**Expected Output :**

```
2 -> b
4 -> d
```

Comment: ```print(i, var[i]) ```

Comment: @DeanTaler  It gives error : `IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try via `zip()`:

```
for x,y in zip(sd.index,sd):
    if y%2==0:
        print(y,'->',x)
```

output:

```
2 -> b
4 -> d
```

Comment: -> what is Zip can you explain in details when to use

Comment: @codeholic24 `zip()` is a built in function in python,basically it is an iterator of tuples

Comment: @codeholic24 iterating `zip(sd.index,sd)` is like iterating values in the list of tuples `[*zip(sd.index,sd)]`

Comment: @codeholic24 kindly see this article for detailed explaination https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip

Answer (score 1):

I did not know about the zip() method so my approach was different.
Using two *for* loops and one variable that was set to be in index 1 at first and then incrementing it by two until the end of the list.

```
m = 1
for i in sd:
  for z in var:
    while m < len(var):
      print(f"{var[m]} ~> {sd[var[m]]}")
      m += 2
```

Comment: can you add try exception to it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both the contributor for helping me : @[Anurag Dabas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14289892/anurag-dabas) and @[Dean Taler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12557235/dean-taler)

I was able to achieve using below method

The solution of @Anurag Dabas is much more accurate then below

Incase required any modification , feel free to edit it

**Code :**

```
dataSet=[11,24,31,46]
varSet=['a','b','c','d']

try:
    
    if len(dataSet) == len(varSet):
        print('The even key pair values are mentioned below')
        for i in range (len(dataSet)):
                if dataSet[i]%2==0:
                    print(str(dataSet[i]) + '-->' + str(varSet[i]))
                else:
                    pass
    else:
        
        raise ValueError
                
except ValueError:
    print(f'Seems like the length does not match : dataSet {len(dataSet)} - varSet : {len(varSet)} ')
    
except Exception as exp:
    print(exp)
```

**Output :**

[image: Expected output]

**Incase the value in one of the list is more then length , then it will throw error message**

for example

`dataSet=[11,24,31,46] -> length : 4` and you append one more value to list : `dataSet=[11,24,31,46,92]` -> length will be : `5`

while comparing  `dataSet` and `varSet` , then length is not equal it will throw error message as below

[image: Error Message]

*If you want to make it work for odd just need to change the* `if condition` *as shown below*

`if not dataSet[i]%2==0:`

Comment: anyway it's upto you that whom answer you wanna accept but as you mention that the other answer is more accurate in your answer......then what is the point of accepting your own answer in that case? and if you want to accept your own answer then what is the point of asking question?